# xsl 1.0 muenchian sum to sum quantity field per compound key

Tags: xslt-1.0

For a SAP PO xsl 1.0 mapping I need to map an 'exotic' file coming from our warehouse where I need to group/sum per order (RECH) a QTY field on a combination of a line identifier (MASTER_PO_LINE_NO) and an Itemnumber (SKU). Each line (RECL) is in a header (RECH).

INPUT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
<MARCXML>
  <RCIC>
    <RECH>
      <SALESID>24000</SALESID>
      <RECL>
        <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
        <QTY_EXPE>1592</QTY_EXPE>
        <SKU>11207-210</SKU>
        <MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>10</MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>
      </RECL>
      <RECL>
        <LINE_NO>2</LINE_NO>
        <QTY_EXPE>1000</QTY_EXPE>
        <SKU>11207-210</SKU>
        <MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>10</MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>
      </RECL>
      <RECL>
        <LINE_NO>3</LINE_NO>
        <QTY_EXPE>175</QTY_EXPE>
        <SKU>11207-210</SKU>
        <MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>20</MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>
      </RECL>
    </RECH>
    <RECH>
      <SALESID>25001</SALESID>
      <RECL>
        <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
        <QTY_EXPE>440</QTY_EXPE>
        <SKU>20000-210</SKU>
        <MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>10</MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>
      </RECL>
    </RECH>
  </RCIC>
</MARCXML>
 </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Required OUTPUT (Qty for 11207-210 = 1592 + 1000):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
<MARCXML>
  <RCIC>
    <RECH>
      <SALESID>24000</SALESID>
      <RECL>
        <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
        <QTY_EXPE>2592</QTY_EXPE>
        <SKU>11207-210</SKU>
        <MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>10</MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>
      </RECL>
      <RECL>
        <LINE_NO>3</LINE_NO>
        <QTY_EXPE>175</QTY_EXPE>
        <SKU>11207-210</SKU>
        <MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>20</MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>
      </RECL>
    </RECH>
    <RECH>
      <SALESID>25001</SALESID>
      <RECL>
        <LINE_NO>1</LINE_NO>
        <QTY_EXPE>440</QTY_EXPE>
        <SKU>20000-210</SKU>
        <MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>10</MASTER_PO_LINE_NO>
      </RECL>
    </RECH>
  </RCIC>
</MARCXML>
 </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

There are plenty of examples about muenchian grouping but I didn't manage to solve my requirement yet. To be honest I got as far as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
      <MARCXML>
         <RCIC>
            <RECH>5284</RECH>
            <RECH>5284</RECH>
            <RECH>5284</RECH>
         </RCIC>
      </MARCXML>
   </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

With the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


    <xsl:key name="kMSTR_PO_LN_SKU" match="RECL"
     use="concat(MASTER_PO_LINE_NO, '#', SKU)"/>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RECH">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(//MARCXML/RCIC/RECH/RECL/QTY_CHECKED_IN)" />

            <xsl:for-each select="/RECL[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kMSTR_PO_LN_SKU',concat(MASTER_PO_LINE_NO,'-',SKU))[1])]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <SKU>
                        <xsl:value-of select="SKU"/>
                    </SKU>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kMSTR_PO_LN_SKU',concat(MASTER_PO_LINE_NO,'-',RECL))/QTY_EXPE)"/>
                    </Quantity>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope someone can help me on my way here

Comment: The missing part in your description is this: should `RECL` nodes having matching `SKU` and `MASTER_PO_LINE_NO` but different  `RECH` parents be grouped together? I would guess no (since your output keeps the `RECH` nodes), but that's just guessing.

Comment: Right Michael, I'll update my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, this produces the required output - but having only a single example with somewhat ambiguous rules it could be a coincidence. In any case, it should provide you with a starting point.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="RECL" use="concat(MASTER_PO_LINE_NO, '|', SKU)"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RECH">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="SALESID"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="RECL[generate-id()=generate-id(key('k1', concat(MASTER_PO_LINE_NO,'|',SKU))[1])]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="LINE_NO"/>
                <QTY_EXPE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('k1', concat(MASTER_PO_LINE_NO,'|',SKU))/QTY_EXPE)" />
                </QTY_EXPE>
                <xsl:copy-of select="SKU | MASTER_PO_LINE_NO"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

In order to summarize every order (`RECH`) separately, you must add an identifier of the order to the key:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="RECL" use="concat(MASTER_PO_LINE_NO, '|', SKU, '|', generate-id(..))"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RECH">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="SALESID"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="RECL[generate-id()=generate-id(key('k1', concat(MASTER_PO_LINE_NO,'|',SKU, '|', generate-id(..)))[1])]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="LINE_NO"/>
                <QTY_EXPE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('k1', concat(MASTER_PO_LINE_NO,'|',SKU, '|', generate-id(..)))/QTY_EXPE)" />
                </QTY_EXPE>
                <xsl:copy-of select="SKU | MASTER_PO_LINE_NO"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thnx Michael! I'm getting one header (1 order) with 1 line with qty 5284. For the first header (RECH) I need 2 lines because altough the item (SKU) is the same the MASTER_PO_LINE_NO for LINE_NO 3 is different (20 vs 10) and I also want to see the output for the separate second header with salesid 25001 with QTY_EXPE 440. As you rightly pointed out my question could be more clearer. Sorry for that..

Comment: My result is different from yours - see: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/jyH9rLX. -- I will address the problem of separating the orders in a short. while.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Works perfect on xsltransform.kimatu.com (thnx for the link!) and also in Visual Studio. I still get 'strange' output on Eclipse (processor Xalan 2.7.1) but your solution to my problem is super, much appreciated!!

Comment: I cannot tell you how happy I am with your help! This real-life example helps me understanding xsl with my own use cases. Thnx a million!