# xsl 1.0 muenchian sum to sum quantity attribute field per compound key

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I recently posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950507/xsl-1-0-muenchian-sum-to-sum-quantity-field-per-compound-key/53950808?noredirect=1#comment94746757_53950808) here for a similar requirement but now I need to do a group / sum on an xml with attributes. I want to sum all quantity attribute values based on the article and status attributes.

The input xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StockAdjustments xmlns="http://vsystems.com/WS/StockAdjustments">
    <StockAdjustment Article="36282" Client="AJA" Status="" Unit="ST" Quantity="-25" ReasonCode="OVERIG" Batch="" HostLocation="C" />
    <StockAdjustment Article="36282" Client="AJA" Status="QUARANTAINE" Unit="ST" Quantity="25" ReasonCode="OVERIG" Batch="" HostLocation="C" />
    <StockAdjustment Article="36282" Client="AJA" Status="" Unit="ST" Quantity="-25" ReasonCode="OVERIG" Batch="" HostLocation="C" />
    <StockAdjustment Article="36282" Client="AJA" Status="QUARANTAINE" Unit="ST" Quantity="25" ReasonCode="OVERIG" Batch="" HostLocation="C" />
    <StockAdjustment Article="36282" Client="AJA" Status="" Unit="ST" Quantity="-25" ReasonCode="OVERIG" Batch="" HostLocation="C" />
    <StockAdjustment Article="36282" Client="AJA" Status="QUARANTAINE" Unit="ST" Quantity="25" ReasonCode="OVERIG" Batch="" HostLocation="C" />
</StockAdjustments>
```

Requested output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StockAdjustments xmlns="http://vsystems.com/WS/StockAdjustments">
    <StockAdjustment Article="36282" Client="AJA" Status="" Unit="ST" Quantity="-75" ReasonCode="OVERIG" Batch="" HostLocation="C" />
    <StockAdjustment Article="36282" Client="AJA" Status="QUARANTAINE" Unit="ST" Quantity="75" ReasonCode="OVERIG" Batch="" HostLocation="C" />
</StockAdjustments>
```

The xsl (which isn't working at all yet) I've created:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:iws="http://vsystems.com/WS/StockAdjustments"
exclude-result-prefixes="iws">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:key name="k1" match="/iws:StockAdjustment" use="concat(@Article, '|', @Status)"/>


<xsl:template match="/iws:StockAdjustments">
<xsl:copy> 
22
        <xsl:for-each select="/iws:StockAdjustment[generate-id()=generate-id(key('k1', concat(@Article,'|',@Status))[1])]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@Article"/>
                <QTY_EXPE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('k1', concat(@Article,'|',@Status))/@Quantity)" />
                </QTY_EXPE>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xsl 1.0 (SAP PO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the `/` symbol. Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:iws="http://vsystems.com/WS/StockAdjustments"
exclude-result-prefixes="iws">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="iws:StockAdjustment" use="concat(@Article, '|', @Status)"/>

<xsl:template match="/iws:StockAdjustments">
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:for-each select="iws:StockAdjustment[generate-id()=generate-id(key('k1', concat(@Article,'|',@Status))[1])]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@Article"/>
                <QTY_EXPE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('k1', concat(@Article,'|',@Status))/@Quantity)" />
                </QTY_EXPE>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

The result is not what you posted, but I went with your attempt. The sums are correct, at any rate.

Comment: Bingo! Didn't realize I was that close ;) Thanks a lot Michael!

Comment: If the outcome of a sum is 0 I don't want it in my output. Can I do this in the same xsl? I have a filter <xsl:template match="iws:StockAdjustments[not (StockAdjustment/@Quantity = 0)]"> but that only validates the input xml not the result of the sum (sometimes I have +128 / -128).

Comment: You need to check the sum of each distinct group, which means you must do it within the `xsl:for-each` block. Start by placing the sum in a variable, then use `xsl:if` around the actual output parts.

Comment: Thnx Michael! One other thing. I have lower and upper cases in my Client attribute (comp1 / COMP1). If I use translate(@Client, $uppercase, $lowercase) in both key and sum it works fine in eclipse, no problem. But I noticed xsltransform fails with 'key may not contain reference to variables'.

Comment: A match pattern in XSLT 1.0 is not allowed to use a variable. So use the actual strings when defining the key element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0" xmlns:mn="http://vsystems.com/WS/StockAdjustments">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="mn:StockAdjustments">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mn:StockAdjustment[@Status = ''][1]">
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:if test="@Article">
                <xsl:attribute name="Article">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Article"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Client">
                <xsl:attribute name="Client">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Client"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Status">
                <xsl:attribute name="Status">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Status"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Unit">
                <xsl:attribute name="Unit">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Unit"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Status = ''">
                <xsl:attribute name="Quantity">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//mn:StockAdjustment[@Status = '']/@Quantity)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@ReasonCode">
                <xsl:attribute name="ReasonCode">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ReasonCode"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Batch">
                <xsl:attribute name="Batch">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Batch"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@HostLocation">
                <xsl:attribute name="HostLocation">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@HostLocation"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="mn:StockAdjustment[@Status = 'QUARANTAINE'][1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="@Article">
                <xsl:attribute name="Article">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Article"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Client">
                <xsl:attribute name="Client">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Client"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Status">
                <xsl:attribute name="Status">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Status"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Unit">
                <xsl:attribute name="Unit">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Unit"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Status = 'QUARANTAINE'">
                <xsl:attribute name="Quantity">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//mn:StockAdjustment[@Status = 'QUARANTAINE']/@Quantity)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@ReasonCode">
                <xsl:attribute name="ReasonCode">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ReasonCode"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@Batch">
                <xsl:attribute name="Batch">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Batch"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@HostLocation">
                <xsl:attribute name="HostLocation">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@HostLocation"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet> 
please check if it is suitable for you.
```

Comment: Hi Imran, different approach but might come in handy in the future in SAP PO because we have different systems / requirements. Really learning a lot from you guys, thank you!